# Get exact language object from display name

Tags: python, localization, ietf-bcp-47, iso-639

Using [langcodes](https://github.com/rspeer/langcodes) package, how do I obtain the exact language object from the display name? For example,

`langcodes.find("English (United Kingdom)")` returns `Language.make(language='en')`

instead of returning `Language.make(language='en', territory='GB')` which is returned by `langcodes.get("en-GB")`

I want to use this to check, for example if `"English (United Kingdom)"` == `en-GB`

Comment: I guess the package knows that the United Kingdom and Great Britain are not the same.

Comment: @KlausD. I have tried English (Great Britain) as well

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it doesn't look like the package supports that functionality. From [the docs](https://github.com/rspeer/langcodes#recognizing-language-names-in-natural-language): [T]his method currently ignores the parenthetical expressions that come from `.display_name()`. This means that `find` would not be able to return the territory from expressions like "English (United States)" or "English (United Kingdom)".
If you absolutely must use this package, the best option I can see is doing some sort of reverse-engineering of the `Language.display_name` method found [here](https://github.com/rspeer/langcodes/blob/master/langcodes/__init__.py#L944).